# How to send mail when node is published

Tags: rules

I have a content type "Properties". By default, content type is set to "Not published"

When users add a node of the content type, node is not published.

Another role gets a notification and then publishes the node.

Once the node is published, an email should be sent out to multiple roles.

I used Rules module to do that but emails are not being send out once nodes are published. I also created other rules and emails are being send out just fine. I am not sure why this specific rule does not send emails.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your scenario it seems that your event is wrong. The content is already saved before. So you should use an event like after updating existing content, of type "Properties". If you then also replace your condition by 2 conditions to check that (a) the unsaved node is unpublished and (b) the saved node is published, you should be close to what you want.

Try it, and see what happens ...the bets are open ...